# 404 error when in ulr without slash in end

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I use this url `http://localhost/backend/backend/page/index`, that it goes to 404 error page, but when I **add** `/` in the end of url, it works correctly.

I mean this url: `http://localhost/backend/page/index/`

Of course this problem is just for **one** of my urls. Other urls works `without` slash in ending url.

I have to add this, that the same url, that I have the same codes on another project, works without problem, and I don't need to add `/` in end of url. The problem is just in this project.

I use no urlmapping in my codes.

If you need more information, ask it.

Comment: Please update your question with UrlManager config.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1807) and [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7670) discussion as well.

Comment: @Yupik I have no  UrlManager config in component

Comment: @Bizley I've seen those before. but I don't use pretyUrl, I think my problem is different. as I said, I have the same page in another project, that works without `/` in there

Comment: @MohammadAghayari u pasted Url without index.php, so u have to use UrlManager for that, or weird rewrite engine, which is not posted here

Comment: @MohammadAghayari without `enablePrettyUrl` your URL would be more like `http://localhost/backend/index.php?r=fcadmin/page/index`

Comment: @Bizley do you mean config on `/backend/config/main.php`

Comment: @MohammadAghayari any config that is applied here. With advanced project configuration is usually merged: common/main + common/main-local + backend/main + backend/main-local

Comment: @Bizley I have the same config in another project, that it woks without any problem